# How to get data from database based on Many to many relation in Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel

I have two models:

```
class Musician extends Model
{
    public function instruments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Instrument', 'musicians_instruments');
    }

}
```

and

```
class Instrument extends Model
{
    public function musicians()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Musician', 'musicians_instruments');

    }
}
```

Saving to database works OK, like I want to. I have 3 tables in database:

```
musicians
instruments
musicians_instruments (pivot table)
```

instruments - example content:

```
id   name
1    guitar
2    piano
3    keyboard
4    DJ
```

When musician register he could choose from 1 to 3 instruments he plays.
For example when he choose guitar (1) and keyboard (3) in pivot table we have (lets say musician has id 2):

musicians_instruments

```
musician_id   instrument_id
2             1
2             3
```

My question is - please help me how to write query to get all instruments that musician play.
If Joe choose 1, 3 how to take all names of instruments he choose.

below - MusicianController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Musician;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class MusicianController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $musicians = Musician::all(); // it's for other musicians data


        $musician = Musician::with('instruments')->find($musician_id);

        return view('musicians', compact('musicians', 'musician'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Index Page** (List of all Musician with their Instruments):

In your **Controller** use these codes:

```
public function index()
{
    $musicians = App\Musician::with('instruments')->get();
    return view('musicians', compact('musicians', 'musicians'));
}
```

In your **View** use these codes:

```
 @foreach($musicians as $musician)
    {{ $musician->name; }}
    <ul>
      @foreach ($musician->instruments as $instrument)
        <li>{{ $instrument->name }}<br></li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
 @endforeach
```

---

For **Profile Page** (Page of a particular Musician [id = musician_id] with their Instruments):

In your **Controller** use these codes:

```
$musician = App\Musician::where("id",$musician_id)->with('instruments')->first();
return view('your/view/file', ['musician'=> $musician]);
```

In your **View** use these codes:

```
{{ $musician->name }}
@foreach($musician->instruments as $instrument)
    {{ $instrument->name; }}<br>
@endforeach
```

For more details visit: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I tried both answers, error in both in the same place - message `Undefined variable: musician_id` shows in this line of code `$musician = App\Musician::with('instruments')->find($musician_id);`. Maybe it's simple thing but I can't solve it..

Comment: @dmj5 Post your controller please so that I can get your problem.

Comment: I have added MusicianController - method index, if you need more code, please tell me.

Comment: So you want to display a list of all musicians with their instruments or just a particular musician with its instrument.

Comment: For now only list of all musicians with their instruments, but later I want also page of single musician. Right now in view **musicains.blade.php** I have `@foreach($musicians as $music)` loop and I'm getting right data for example `$music->name`. I have also file profile.blade.php with single musician profile, but without instruments and genres - I'm trying to add this things also - but that's another thing. Right now the first - list of all musicians with their instruments.

Comment: I have Edited the above code . check if it works for you.

Comment: Error message appears -> BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()

Comment: Sorry my bad, Change all() with get(). Edited the above code Please check that out.

Comment: Thank you :) now everything works great! That's what I'm looking for. Both codes - for index page and for single musician :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the instruments for each musician by simply using the methods you have defined in the respective Models:

```
$musician = App\Musician::find($musician_id);

$instruments = $musician->instruments()->get();

foreach($instruments as $instrument) {
    // $instrument->name;
}
```

Comment: Or simply `$instruments = $musician->instruments;`. Unless you need a separate query, there's little point to that. You'll want eager loading too, so `Musician::with('instruments') ...`

Comment: also, use please lazy loading to prevent n+1 problem:

App\Musician::with('instruments')->find($musicianId);